# mysql fetch row memory error

Tags: php, mysql, memory

I'm using a modified php mysql backup script I found on the net to backup my sql databases but I kept running into an issue with mysql_fetch_row and I was wondering if there was a way to fix it.

I commented the line with the memory error.

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit','4000M');
$ho = "host";
$us = "username";
$pa = "password";
$da='dbname';

backup_tables($ho,$us,$pa,$da);


/* backup the db OR just a table */
function backup_tables($host,$user,$pass,$name,$tables = '*')
{
    $link = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    mysql_select_db($name,$link);

    //get all of the tables
    if($tables == '*')
    {
        $tables = array();
        $result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
        {
            $tables[] = $row[0];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);
    }

    $filename = 'db-backup-'.time().'-'.(md5(implode(',',$tables))).'.sql';
    $handle = fopen($filename,'w');

    //cycle through
    foreach($tables as $table)
    {
        $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
        $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);

        fwrite( $handle, 'DROP TABLE '.$table.';' );

        $row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
        fwrite( $handle, "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n" );

        for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++)
        {
            //this is the line with the error******
            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
            {
                fwrite( $handle, 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(' );
                for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++)
                {
                    $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
                    $row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
                    if (isset($row[$j])) { fwrite( $handle, '"'.$row[$j].'"' ) ; } 
                    else { fwrite( $handle, '""' ); }

                    if ($j<($num_fields-1)) { fwrite( $handle, ',' ); }
            }
            fwrite( $handle, ");\n" );
       }
     }
    fwrite( $handle, "\n\n\n" );
}

    //save file

    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

and this is the error:

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1338507264) (tried to allocate 35 bytes) in /home/user/backupSQL/backupmodified.php on line 47
```

I know there are better ways to do a backup but this meets all my requirements for my system and I only run into the memory problem with my ridiculously huge databases.

Thanks for the help.

-PHP/MySQL newbie

ps. heres the link i used http://www.htmlcenter.com/blog/back-up-your-mysql-database-with-php/

edit: mysqldump works fine when backing up these large databases, but the large dbs are the most modified ones and I cant have my dbs lock while dumping when someone needs to work on them.  That's why I resorted to this script.

Comment: If your database is so large that this is not scaling to its memory needs, I would argue that it _is not meeting_ your requirements.  This really is a job for `mysqldump`... especially considering this only dumps tables, and not any triggers, or procedures you may eventually need to define.

Comment: I was initially doing dumps with mysqldump but the issue is that I would backup overnight and it would lock the databases during the dump and prevent people overseas from modifying them. Currently using Myisam dbs and this script would allow me to backup without locking down the dbs onto a remote pc.  I'm getting new servers but thats in a few months so this is a temporary solution for me to backup my dbs as I will be implementing something different.  Oh and replication is broken too because of the use of temp tables, which is needed in my server.

Comment: I'll edit my post to clarify more about my situation. thanks for the response though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other posters have mentioned, you would be better off using a ready-made tool, but let's talk about your script for now.

If you have a ridiculously large table, then there's just no way to allocate that much memory. You'll have to split your data set into multiple chunks. Use a query like:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table.' LIMIT '.$start.', 10000');
```

Then just iterate with `$start` or do a `while` loop to check if you're still getting results. Like this, you'll get the data in chunks of 10000 records so it'll surely fit in your memory.

There's still a problem, though – consistency. What if some rows change while you're still fetching chunks? Well, you could wrap your `SELECT` loop in a transaction and lock the table while you're getting the data. I know you're trying to avoid locks, but locking a table is better than an entire database. This still won't ensure inter-table consistency, but it's the best that can be done under the conditions you set.

EDIT: Here is the code for the loop. I implemented the `while` solution. There is an equivalent `for` loop, but the comparison between the two is outside the scope of this post.

```
foreach($tables as $table)
{
    fwrite( $handle, 'DROP TABLE '.$table.';' );

    $row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
    fwrite( $handle, "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n" );

    $start = 0;
    do {
        $result = mysql_query( 'SELECT * FROM '.$table.' LIMIT '.$start.', 10000' );
        $start += 10000;
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows( $result );

        while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $result ) ) {
            $line = 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
            foreach( $row as $value ) {
                $value = addslashes( $value );
                $value = ereg_replace( "\n","\\n", $value );
                $line .= '"'.$value.'",';
            }
            $line = substr( $line, 0, -1 ); // cut the final ','
            $line .= ');\n';
            fwrite( $handle, $line );
        }
    } while( $num_rows !== 0 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! question though, how would iterate to the rest of the query?

Comment: would I call the query again and it would spit out the next 10k lines? like while($result = mysql_query(.......);  same exact line? or would it be another query command?

Comment: oh thats what you mean by iterate $start. Didn't know you could do that with limit. Learning something new everyday. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The *mysql* extension has the [`mysql_unbuffered_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-unbuffered-query.php) function specifically designed for queries on large databases.

The equivalent in *mysqli* leverages the second argument of [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), e.g.:

```
$res = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM large_database', MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    ...
}
```

This method has some drawbacks though, e.g. you cannot know the number of rows in `$res` and you cannot execute other queries until `$res` has been freed.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite typical problem that dump allocates amount of memory that is proportional to the table size in some way. You should implement in your script similar to "--opt" option in mysqldump and look how to dump big databases for example here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-can-i-optimize-a-mysqldump-of-a-large-database

Why not just use **mysqldump** logging the output to some file?

Comment: answered this in the comment above, but mysqldump locks my databases down and prevent people from working on them while dumping.  that was how I was backing them up initially before running into the locking issue.

Comment: Ill probably put that in my original post. Thanks for the response though. Ill read into that link too.

Comment: You can do a mysqldumps without a lock :) (just read the mysqldump man)

Comment: I have read that if i do with no locks, and its being modified then the entire backup is unusable? plus dumping takes a long time for these big databases so I dont really have time to test that.